# Creating various road symbols with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to create three road symbols with TikZ. These are

- US Interstate Shield

[image: US Interstate Shield image]

- US Highway Shield

[image: US Highway Shield image]

- Generic State Highway "pill". This is basically a rectangle capped with two semi-circles.

I have created a package like so...

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}                                      
\ProvidesPackage{roadsymbols}[Some TiKz picutres for road symbols]                                                  
                                                                               
\RequirePackage{tikz}                                                                        
                                                                                                     
% interstate                                                                                 
% TODO Use U.S. Intertate Shield                                                                     
\newcommand{\istate}[1]{%                                                                       
  \begin{tikzpicture}                                                                     
    \node {#1};                                                                                 
  \end{tikzpicture}                                           
  }

% national highway                                            
% TODO Use U.S. Highway Shield
\newcommand{\hwy}[1]{%                                        
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node {#1};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }
                                                              
% state highway
\newcommand{\shwy}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (0,0) {#1};
    \draw (-8pt, 6pt) -- (8pt, 6pt);
    \draw (-8pt, -6pt) -- (8pt, -6pt);
    \draw (-8pt, 6pt) arc (90:270:6pt);
    \draw (8pt, 6pt) arc (90:-90:6pt);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }

% TODO Can these be make to fix the text they contain _horizontally_?
```

I was able to get the "pill" done, as shown above.

The idea is to have a command which will print out *just the outline* of these symbols with the given text inside them. I am inexperienced with TikZ and I honestly have no idea how I would start going about the more complicated shapes in an accurate manner. As a bonus, the symbols can be a fixed height (slightly larger than the text size within), but ideally they'd grow horizontally to accommodate. My pill does not do this stretching right now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!!! This is an example of the first shield, using Ti*k*Z `spath3` library. I think that with a lot of clips (a very big lot) you can do the same, but I prefer to do it this way.

**Setting the stage:**
Let's find the contour of the shield and its parts:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1.618mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}\sffamily\bfseries
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach\j in {0,0.1}
{
  \foreach\i in {-1,1}
  {
    \draw  (0.5*\i,0.5) circle (2.5-\j);
    \draw (0.75*\i,4.4) circle (2.5+\j);
  }
  \draw (-2,1.1+\j) --++ (4,0);
}
\node[yscale=1.4] at (0, 1.5) {\large INTERSTATE};
\node[scale =3.5] at (0,-0.1) {\huge 80};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Now the dirty work:** Let's take the blowtorch and get to work, there is much to cut and weld.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1.618mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,spath3}

\definecolor{interstate blue}{HTML}{003F87}
\definecolor{interstate red} {HTML}{Af1E2D}

\begin{document}\sffamily\bfseries
\begin{tikzpicture}
\useasboundingbox (-2.1,-2) rectangle (2.1,2.1);
% creating the paths
\path[spath/save=circleBLO] (-0.5 ,0.5) circle (2.5); % circle bottom left  outer
\path[spath/save=circleBRO]  (0.5 ,0.5) circle (2.5); % circle bottom right outer
\path[spath/save=circleBLI] (-0.5 ,0.5) circle (2.4); % circle bottom left  inner
\path[spath/save=circleBRI]  (0.5 ,0.5) circle (2.4); % ...
\path[spath/save=circleTLO] (-0.75,4.4) circle (2.5);
\path[spath/save=circleTRO]  (0.75,4.4) circle (2.5);
\path[spath/save=circleTLI] (-0.75,4.4) circle (2.6);
\path[spath/save=circleTRI]  (0.75,4.4) circle (2.6);
\path[spath/save=lineB]     (-2   ,1.1) --++   (4,0); % line bottom
\path[spath/save=lineT]     (-2   ,1.2) --++   (4,0); % line top
% spath3 operatios
\tikzset
{% circles have non-visible components, we don't need them
  spath/remove empty components={circleBLO},
  spath/remove empty components={circleBRO},
  spath/remove empty components={circleBLI},
  spath/remove empty components={circleBRI},
  spath/remove empty components={circleTLO},
  spath/remove empty components={circleTRO},
  spath/remove empty components={circleTLI},
  spath/remove empty components={circleTRI},
  % cutting
  spath/split at intersections={circleBLO}{circleBRO},
  spath/split at intersections={circleTLO}{circleTRO},
  spath/split at intersections={circleBLO}{circleTRO},
  spath/split at intersections={circleBRO}{circleTLO},
  spath/split at intersections={circleBLI}{circleBRI},
  spath/split at intersections={circleBLI}{circleTRI},
  spath/split at intersections={circleBRI}{circleTLI},
  spath/split at intersections={circleTLI}{circleTRI},
  spath/split at intersections={circleBLI}{lineB},
  spath/split at intersections={circleBRI}{lineB},
  spath/split at intersections={circleBLI}{lineT},
  spath/split at intersections={circleBRI}{lineT},
  % store the pieces
  spath/get components of={circleBLO}\cBLO,
  spath/get components of={circleBRO}\cBRO,
  spath/get components of={circleTLO}\cTLO,
  spath/get components of={circleTRO}\cTRO,
  spath/get components of={circleBLI}\cBLI,
  spath/get components of={circleBRI}\cBRI,
  spath/get components of={circleTLI}\cTLI,
  spath/get components of={circleTRI}\cTRI,
  spath/get components of={lineB}\lB,
  spath/get components of={lineT}\lT,
}
% shield
\draw[
      spath/use=\getComponentOf\cBLO{3},
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\cTRO{3},reverse,weld},
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\cTLO{2},reverse,weld},
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\cBRO{2},weld},
     ];
% 80
\fill[interstate blue,
      spath/use=\getComponentOf\cBLI{3},
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\lB{1},weld},
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\cBRI{4},weld},
     ];
% interstate
\fill[interstate red,
      spath/use=\getComponentOf\cBLI{5},
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\cTRI{2},reverse,weld},
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\cTLI{1},reverse,weld},
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\cBRI{2},weld},
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\lT{2},weld},
     ];
% labels
\node[yscale=1.4,white] at (0, 1.5) {\large INTERSTATE};
\node[scale =3.5,white] at (0,-0.1) {\huge 80};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh wow, this is great! I never thought about thinking of them as intersecting circles! I'll give another go at the highway symbol. I'll comment here when I have something I am pleased with. Thank you!

Comment: I am most of the way there with the highway symbol, but I am dealing with issues with the `spath/split at intersections` key. The highway symbol had to be made with many tangential circles, not intersecting ones. This seems to cause the intersection points to be poorly calculated in those places. I looked at `texdoc spath3` but am unable to find anything related to this. Do you have any pointers of where to look for splitting these types of paths? Maybe I could try creating paths which are normal to where these circles are tangent and do the splits with those instead?

Comment: @Logan, I had the same issues in other pictures. The precision finding the intersections is not veri good in Ti*k*Z, specially at the tangent points. In these cases i draw an auxiliary line that cuts both curves and use it to split them

Comment: I did exactly that and got something that worked. I was able to create [these two symbols](https://github.com/lgrosz/roadsigns/blob/master/examples.tex) (the first is pretty much just a simplified version of yours), but I'm proud of the highway symbol. Thank you, again!

Comment: @Logan, very good, I like it!!! :-D